# compute semantic PMI for two words using wikipedia

Tags: nlp, text-mining, dbpedia

I am trying to compute pointwise mutual information (PMI) using wikipedia as data source. Given two words, PMI defines the relation between two words. The formula is as below.

`pmi(word1,word2) = log [probability(number of times both words appears in a document together)/probability(word1)*probability(word2)].`

Hence to compute PMI, I would need joint and individual probabilities of word1 and word2. I looked at the wikipedia miner relatedness score between two words. They are implementing a Milne and Witten algorithm. However, for defining topic similarities, PMI is a better score.

Does any one know how to compute PMI score for two words using dbpedia or wikipedia miner or any other software.

Comment: Count the words, apply above equation. What is your question exactly?

Comment: I am performing a topic modeling and want to understand the topic similarity using semantically. Recent papers show pmi score computed using wikipedia better than WordNet similarity. Instead of downloading and computing these scores manually, is there a library or service that I can use. For eg., dbpedia, wiki miner etc.

Comment: Questions asking for library, tool, service and other off-site recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: I always thought about stackoverflow as a forum to discuss about implementation issues. Btw, dbpedia is indeed a service and we discuss about how to perform some operations on dbpedia.

Comment: Implementation questions are good. But they should involve code, not only libraries and web services to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of solutions I found recently would work.

1. For python interface use dissect. Dissect need co occurence matrix as input. Co occurence matrix can be constructed using python easily.
2. I also liked the [Palmetto project](https://github.com/AKSW/Palmetto.) in github. For Palmetto you need to create lucene index. They provide code snippet to build the lucene indices.

Comment: The link is broken now, but Palmetto resolves the problem mentioned by OP. So, here is the new link: 
https://github.com/AKSW/Palmetto/wiki/Coherences